# Kendo TreeView Sync method on datasource not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have Kendo TreeView in which I can Call an Ajax method and hit my MVC controller method

However, my understanding was that

**update:**   "should" be called with **datasource.sync()**   ( homogeneous = my datasource )

```
$("#syncCall").click(function(e) {
   console.log('before sync');
   homogeneous.sync();
});
```

This **DOES** show **before sync**  in chrome dev console ....

However, my mvc controller method **SyncAllNodes** **breakpoint** is **NEVER** hit.

Here is the **HierarchicalDataSource**

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({

                                    transport: {
                                        read: {
                                            url: serviceRoot + "/GetReportGroupAssignments", 
                                            dataType: "json" 
                                        },
                                        update: {
                                            url: "/Report/SyncAllNodes",
                                            dataType: "json"
                                        }
                                    },

                                    schema: {
                                        model: {
                                            id: "Id" //"ReportGroupName"
                                            ,
                                            hasChildren: "Id"

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Joseph,

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but your Update url looks different than your Read url.  Namely, the "serviceRoot +" part.  Can you verify that the Update url points to the correct location?

Are you getting any javascript errors after the console.log(...) call?

Also, confirm that you have changes to save.  If there are no changes, the sync method will not do anything.

Regards,

Comment: Ok, I figured it out ,  sync is ONLY calling the update url when data changes...    however I was getting "data not found"  when I would create a new parent node ...  not sure how to interrogate the sync() method to get "under the covers" to see what is happening....